# Symfony security and twig Render funcion

Tags: security, symfony, routes, twig, render

I have this scenario.
My site has a secured part. Security is, I think, correctly configured.
If I try to open a secured URL from browser, I am asked to type username and password.
Symfony profiler shows correctly user context after logon
The homepage (root route) is not secured (the profiler shows here the anonymous context)

Now the problem:
If, in the twig template of the homepage, I put something like this

```
{{ render(path('secured_route')) }}
```

the content of the secured route is rendered!
I expected to get some kind of exception or the login window!
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendering a controller this way, you're bypassing the router, so securities related to routes are bypassed too.

The best you can do is to restraint your controller to logged-in users using the [@Security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html) annotation:

```
/**
 * @Security("has_role('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')")
 */
```

Comment: So, every controller shuld check for permissions. Managing security at route level seems pointless.

Comment: Every controller and every service methods as well if it requires security checks.

Answer (score 0):

By using "render" from twig you are skipping the security checks related to routes, if you don't need to get the content in the anonymous context, you could check the role from Twig before rendering the controller, something like:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
  {{ render(path('secured_route')) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Then don't use {{ render(path('secured_route')) }} in the view, and handle the security from the controller